# error for object 0x7ff368504170: pointer being freed was not allocated?

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

How am i able to tell from where in my code this error is coming from? I am using sublime as my text editor and am familiar with the debugger GDB, but i have no idea where to set my breakpoints?

This is the error I keep getting:

```
a.out(55175,0x112a91dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff368504170: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(55175,0x112a91dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

For reference I am implementing a AVL tree, and therefore using a lot of pointers. From my understanding this is most likely the root of the problem. But I am unsure as to which pointers are causing the error.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are calling the free() method for a pointer which has not been allocated memory ( no allocation call with malloc(), etc.)  and is also neither set as NULL. Use debugging around free() call and check for the contents of the pointer before making the call.

Comment: There is no shortcut.  You just have to get your hands dirty and debug your program, starting from scratch, setting breakpoints, using smaller / minimal data samples that reproduce the error, etc.

Comment: You're calling `free` on a stack-allocated value. If you cannot find it by inspection, run your code under `valgrind`.

Comment: The output gives a hint: "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug". Did you do that? On the call stack you should see the caller and thus be able to identify which pointer is being freed.